# The meaning of the surname Hooch

Tags: translation

Madam Hooch from the book of Harry Potter in Russian translation she is called like Madam Hooch or Madam Tryuck(it's mean trick). I found a translation of the word hooch - marijuana or alcoholic drink.

Is there another translation of this word?

Comment: Check out the slang word [hoochie](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hoochie), which is sometimes also shortened to _hooch_. (I'm not saying that Rowling was trying to convey something, but it's another way I've heard the word _hooch_ used.) There is more than one way to interpret that name  – and more than one way that doesn't end up being very flattering. But Rowling does have a penchant for including a lot of very unusual names in the _Harry Potter_ series.

Comment: J.R., eh. Just missing a K. We're onto you. That said, I'd also ask whether there's any chance she is called "Hooch" simply because it's similar to "Hoop" (as in "Quidditch Hoop").

Comment: alexander - You might find [this](http://www.accio-quote.org/themes/names.htm) an interesting place to start. Near the end, she is quoted as saying, "I love freakish names." (Nothing there about Hooch, though, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 1):

"Hooch" is generally used in America to mean an alcoholic drink, usually one which is homemade or illegal, such as moonshine made by people in the country.  It can often be considered rough to drink and may have some additional odd ingredients.

"Hooch" [can also mean](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hooch) a thatched Asian hut, sometimes associated with prostitution.  It seems to have come from military men employing prostitutes or having "kept" women in Asian countries.  This may be the origin of "hoochie-coochie" and "hoochie", describing women who are sexually provocative.

I also came across [a reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hooch-verb.1250183/) to "hooch" as a verb.  I hadn't seen it before, but it may be a slang work meaning to slide up in a sly way, perhaps coming from "scoot" and "scooch", along with with the dishonest or sneaky associations of "hooch" as a beverage.